# How to put DOUBLE with decimal place to JSONObject?

Tags: android, double, json

using JSONObject to send to web service
when we put double (round number) the zero and the point gets removed

CODE

```
double d = 123.00;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("param", d);
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Output

```
{"param":17}
```

Can I put double with decimal place to JSONObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getDouble(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble%28java.lang.String%29) to read that value.

Like

```
System.out.println(json.getDouble("param"));
```

---

If you see `toString()` of JSONObject

```
663 public String toString(int indentSpaces) throws JSONException {
664        JSONStringer stringer = new JSONStringer(indentSpaces);
665        writeTo(stringer);
666        return stringer.toString();
667    }
668
669    void writeTo(JSONStringer stringer) throws JSONException {
670        stringer.object();
671        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : nameValuePairs.entrySet()) {
672            stringer.key(entry.getKey()).value(entry.getValue());
673        }
674        stringer.endObject();
675    }
```

`writeTo()` writes values as `Object`. So it might be the reason of `toString()` showing unexpected value for double.

Comment: `getDouble()` truncates double to one decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Na, better use this function, even when u cast float to double:

```
public static double roundToDouble(float d, int decimalPlace) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(d));
        bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
```